# Any reason to assign -0?

Tags: c, numbers, integer, lint

I am going through some old C code using Lint which stumbled upon this line:

```
int16_t max = -0;
```

The Lint message is that the "Constant expression evaluates to 0 in operation '-'".

Is there any reason why someone would use -0?

Comment: If the target architecture has negative `0` for `int`

Comment: Perhaps it is a tilde `~` not a minus `-` ?

Comment: @Olaf: What architectures had that, and why was it useful?

Comment: `~0` does not evaluate to zero in any architecture, AFAIK.

Comment: IEEE floating point does support positive and negative zeros.  I'm not aware of any architecture with an integral type that has both positive and negative zeros.

Comment: @Peter: The C standard allows for different representation of signed integers. sign/magnitude would be such an encoding. Not sure which standard CPU might have used it, but a custom FPGA CPU or a DSP comes to mind.

Comment: The current architecture is ARM but it used to be Atmel, not sure if the code is inherited from that.

Comment: @qnyz: Atmel is a manufacturer, not a CPU architecture. They also used to have FPGAs/CPLDs. ARM is also very broad (but they all use 2s complement), as it spreads from ARMv4 (ARM7) to ARMv8 (Cortex-A 64 bit) (yes, there were ARMv2/3, but these are very likely not used for a current system). Anyway, without further information, it is very hard to tell.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, I am aware that Atmel is a manufacturer, it's just that I don't know what CPU was used, only that it came from Atmel. The current architecture is Cortex M3.

Comment: Simple answer: analyse to code. As it is an initializer and according to the name, I would suspect it should set `max` to the lowest possible value before finding the maximum of an array or incoming data or similar. Whether this is meant to be `0` or it should actually be `INT16_MIN` depends on the allowed range of values (although for such an algorithm the second value would always work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I can't see any reason for this. Others have mentioned that it is possible to have platforms with "negative zero", but such a negative zero can never be produced by this expression, so this is useless.

The corresponding paragraph in the C standard is 6.2.6.2 p3, emphasis is mine:

> If the implementation supports negative zeros, they shall be generated
>   only by:
>
> — the &, |, ^, ~, <<, and >> operators with operands that
>     produce such a value;
>
> — the +, -, *, /, and % operators **where one operand is a negative zero** and the result is zero;
>
> — compound
>   assignment operators based on the above cases.

To produce a negative zero on such a platform you could use `~INT_MAX`, for example, but that would not be a zero for other representations, so the code wouldn't be very portable.

Comment: Hmmm: 6.2.6.2 seems to even preclude `long mz = strtol("-0", NULL, 10)` from creating `-0` even when implementation supports negative zeros.

Comment: @chux, yes I think so. The whole idea is that negative zero should be avoided by the architecture where they can. They should only be produced by bit manipulations, where they are unavoidable.

Comment: I agree with your claim, but the coder might have thought different or he used a non-standard compiler. This is an embedded device, and old code, so it is quite likely the compiler had some extensions/modifications (pretty common some years ago).

Answer (score 7):

In the C specification *(6.2.6.2 Integer types)*, it states the following (emphasis mine):

> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits; there shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are
>   M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M £ N). If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value. **If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the following ways:**
>
> - the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (*sign and
>     magnitude*);
> - the sign bit has the value -(2N) (*two’s complement*);
> - the sign bit has the value -(2N - 1) (*one’s complement*).
>
> Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the
>   value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or
>   with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for one’s complement), is a trap
>   representation or a normal value. **In the case of sign and magnitude
>   and one’s complement, if this representation is a normal value it is
>   called a negative zero**.

In other words, C supports three different [representations for signed integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) and two of them have the concept of [*signed zero*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), which makes a distinction between a positive and a negative zero.

So, my explanation is that perhaps the author of your code snippet was trying to produce a negative zero value. But, as pointed out in [Jens Gustedt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32719309/1892179), this expression cannot actually produce a negative zero, which means the author may have made a wrong assumption there.

Answer (score 0):

That is for an architecture using a CPU with [one's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement) numbers.

- Ones complement is a way to represent negative numbers, having a -0. Still in use for floating point.
- For unsigned numbers the maximal number is indeed `-0` : all 1s.

We are accustomed to two's complement numbers, having one negative number more. Though one's complement has some troubles around zero, the same holds for two's complement around MIN_INT: `-MIN_INT == MIN_INT`.

In the code above probably intended was unsigned numbers:

```
uint16_t max = (uint16_t) -1;
```

Comment: Could also be sign/magnitude.

Comment: @Olaf yes, though then max 100000 would be the number after the maximal signed int, somehow not useful.

Comment: Hmm.. is that binary`100000`? Why would that be the "the number after `INT_MAX`? It is a negative `0`, as for 1s complement.

Comment: @Olaf. Right, `for (int i = 0; i != max; ++i)` would be one terrible usage.

Comment: Whoever writes such loops should not show up at my company.

Answer (score 0):

No reason for it with C99 or later.

`int16_t` is an exact-width integer type.

> The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a **two’s complement representation**. Thus, `int8_t` denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.  C11dr  §7.20.1.1 1

There is no signed zero with two’s complement.  So code is equivalent to

```
int16_t max = 0;
```

---

IMO, the `int16_t max = -0;` *hoped* for result, on a non-2's complement platform,  was to initialize `max` to `-0` to flag an array of length 0 or one that only contained elements with the value `-0`.